# how to switch background gradient smoothly

Tags: html, css, css-animations

trying to change background gradient smoothly from `gold-orange` - to `orange-gold` and vice versa

problem - colors are changed suddenly, jumping from one to another

pls help

```css
.box {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, gold, orange);
  animation: back infinite;
  animation-duration: 7s;
}

@keyframes back {
  0% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, gold, orange);
  }
  50% {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, gold, orange);
  }
  100% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, gold, orange);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase `background-size` and use `background-position` for the animation

```css
.box {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, gold, orange, gold);
  animation: back ease infinite;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  background-size: 200% 200%;
}

@keyframes back {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 0%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```

Comment: interesting. Have you any idea why the `normal way` doesn't work ?

Comment: @provanve because `linear-gradient` is an `<image>` and there is no transitionning on `<image>`. Note that an alternative would have been to animate transparency instead for a fade result: https://jsfiddle.net/a5fjus6n/

Comment: `gradient` is a special background and it cannot be animated in usual cases. If you're looking for an advanced way, you can try to have @property. Here is very useful article for gradient animation https://dev.to/afif/we-can-finally-animate-css-gradient-kdk @provance